# Belkin Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB A ports not detected in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, usb, 18.04, thunderbolt, peripherals

I have a Lenovo Yoga 920 i7-8550U with Ubuntu 18.04 on it. I got the Belkin Thunderbolt 3 Dock which I connect via the included USB C cable to the USB C/Thunderbolt 3 port on the laptop. The exact model name is "Thunderbolt™ 3 Express Dock HD - Dual 4k Display, 85W PSU" and can be found [here](https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U095/), [here](https://hipsterpixel.co/2017/07/26/belkin-thunderbolt-3-express-dock-hd/), and [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V24FK8H) (multiple links to prevent bit rot). No devices connected to the USB A ports on the Belkin dock are detected, and there is no output on dmesg. The ports do have power on them, but that's it. The second USB C port on the dock also doesn't recognize USB devices. I connected a keyboard via a USB C to USB A converter, and it couldn't enter any characters. The second USB C port does, however, work with a USB C to DP cable and a monitor connected this way does display the image. Also the DP port on the dock works. Neither lsusb or lspci show the ports. The ports do work under Windows 10 and on a friend's Macbook Pro. What can I do in order to get those ports to work?

```
user@lenovo:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:210d Acer, Inc
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
user@lenovo:~$ lsusb -t
/: Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/: Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/: Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/: Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
|__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
|__ Port 8: Dev 8, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
|__ Port 8: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
user@lenovo:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:15.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #2 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
37:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
6b:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
6c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a808
user@lenovo:~$ lspci -t
-[0000:00]-±00.0
±02.0
±04.0
±08.0
±14.0
±14.2
±15.0
±15.1
±15.3
±16.0
±19.0
±1c.0-[01-6a]----00.0-[02-6a]–±00.0-[03]----00.0
| ±01.0-[04-36]–
| ±02.0-[37]----00.0
| -04.0-[38-6a]–
±1c.4-[6b]----00.0
±1d.0-[6c]----00.0
±1f.0
±1f.2
±1f.3
-1f.4
```

Comment: I have Belkin Thunderbolt 3 dock station, now I'm looking for which laptop to by so it will work. 

is this one that you have: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Thunderbolt-Windows-monitors-upstream-charging/dp/B07Y42ZCMR ?

Comment: @confiq see text. also bear in mind i'd recommend this dock, as it ended up working well with the mac i had it on, works well with the latest macbook pro (intel), and works well with windows based laptops. just get any thunderbolt 3 capable laptop, just make sure the tb3 port has 4 pcie lanes going to it. that'll be mentioned in the laptop's specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, at at some point this just started working on its own after a few reboots and days. I didn't even expect it to work, I just connected my phone to the usb A port to charge it and surprisingly enough it was detected by the OS. It may still be somewhat random; what I did this time was to connect the Thunderbolt 3 dock first, and then turned the Lenovo Yoga 920 on. This is what might have done the trick.

This is what the output of several test commands looks like, with an external disk drive enclosure connected to the front usb A port of the Belkin Thunderbolt 3 dock:

```
user@lenovo:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 1f75:0621 Innostor Technology Corporation 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 08bb:2912 Texas Instruments 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:210d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
user@lenovo:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 8, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
user@lenovo:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:15.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #2 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
05:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:00.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 10)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
37:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
6b:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
6c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a808
user@lenovo:~$ lspci -t
-[0000:00]-+-00.0
           +-02.0
           +-04.0
           +-08.0
           +-14.0
           +-14.2
           +-15.0
           +-15.1
           +-15.3
           +-16.0
           +-19.0
           +-1c.0-[01-6a]----00.0-[02-6a]--+-00.0-[03]----00.0
           |                               +-01.0-[04-36]----00.0-[05-36]--+-00.0-[06]----00.0
           |                               |                               +-01.0-[07]----00.0
           |                               |                               \-04.0-[08-36]--
           |                               +-02.0-[37]----00.0
           |                               \-04.0-[38-6a]--
           +-1c.4-[6b]----00.0
           +-1d.0-[6c]----00.0
           +-1f.0
           +-1f.2
           +-1f.3
           \-1f.4
user@lenovo:~$ lspci -t -v
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620
           +-04.0  Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
           +-08.0  Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
           +-15.1  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1
           +-15.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
           +-19.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #2
           +-1c.0-[01-6a]----00.0-[02-6a]--+-00.0-[03]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
           |                               +-01.0-[04-36]----00.0-[05-36]--+-00.0-[06]----00.0  Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller
           |                               |                               +-01.0-[07]----00.0  Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection
           |                               |                               \-04.0-[08-36]--
           |                               +-02.0-[37]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
           |                               \-04.0-[38-6a]--
           +-1c.4-[6b]----00.0  Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
           +-1d.0-[6c]----00.0  Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a808
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Device 9d4e
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
           \-1f.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
user@lenovo:~$ lsdev
Device            DMA   IRQ  I/O Ports
------------------------------------------------
 accel_3d_consumer0        177 
 als_consumer1          179 
0000:00:02.0                   0000-0000
0000:00:1f.4                   0000-0000
acpi                      9 
ACPI                             0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000
aerdrv, PCIe PME      123 124 
aerdrv, PCIe PME, pciehp        122 
ath10k_pci              157 
cascade             4       
dma                            0000-0000
dma1                           0000-0000
dma2                           0000-0000
dmar0                   120 
dmar1                   121 
EC                               0000-0000     0000-0000
enp7s0                  170 
enp7s0-TxRx-0           171 
enp7s0-TxRx-1           172 
enp7s0-TxRx-2           173 
enp7s0-TxRx-3           174 
fpu                            0000-0000
i2c_designware.0         16 
i2c_designware.1         17 
i2c_designware.2         19 
i8042                     1 
i915                    149 
ITE8353:00               58 
keyboard                       0000-0000   0000-0000
mei_me                  175 
nvme0q0, nvme0q1        148 
nvme0q2                 150 
nvme0q3                 151 
nvme0q4                 152 
nvme0q5                 153 
nvme0q6                 154 
nvme0q7                 155 
nvme0q8                 156 
PCI                          0000-0000 0000-0000 0000-0000   0000-0000     0000-0000       0000-0000
pciehp                127 129 161 
pic1                           0000-0000
pic2                           0000-0000
pnp                            0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000     0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000     0000-0000       0000-0000
PNP0C09:00                     0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000
rtc0                      8    0000-0000
snd_hda_intel:card0        176 
SYNA2B31:00              51 
thunderbolt           132 133 
timer                     0 
timer0                         0000-0000
timer1                         0000-0000
WCOM5110:00              31 
xhci_hcd              130 131 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 
user@lenovo:~$ procinfo
Memory:        Total        Used        Free     Buffers                       
RAM:        16165688     6900280     9265408      142508                       
Swap:        2097148           0     2097148                                   

Bootup: Mon Aug  6 12:26:20 2018   Load average: 1.11 0.95 0.50 2/829 13010    

user  :   00:07:13.39   0.7%  page in :          1299838                       
nice  :   00:00:09.84   0.0%  page out:           712989                       
system:   00:01:41.58   0.2%  page act:           366191                       
IOwait:   00:00:17.46   0.0%  page dea:                0                       
hw irq:   00:00:00.00   0.0%  page flt:          5132191                       
sw irq:   00:00:07.92   0.0%  swap in :                0                       
idle  :   17:27:43.16  99.1%  swap out:                0                       
uptime:   02:12:18.60         context :          4224146                       

irq   0:         10  2-edge timer        irq 152:       4593  56623107-edge nvm
irq   1:       2002  1-edge i8042        irq 153:       5267  56623108-edge nvm
irq   8:          1  8-edge rtc0         irq 154:       5543  56623109-edge nvm
irq   9:       3734  9-fasteoi acpi      irq 155:       4866  56623110-edge nvm
irq  16:       1062  16-fasteoi idma64   irq 156:       5667  56623111-edge nvm
irq  17:    1080562  17-fasteoi idma64   irq 157:      99935  56098816-edge ath
irq  19:     105845  19-fasteoi idma64   irq 161:          0  2686976-edge pcie
irq  31:          1  31-fasteoi WCOM51   irq 162:      29151  3145728-edge xhci
irq  51:      17034  51-fasteoi SYNA2B   irq 163:          0  3145729-edge xhci
irq  58:       6249  58-fasteoi ITE835   irq 164:          0  3145730-edge xhci
irq 120:          0  0-edge dmar0        irq 165:          0  3145731-edge xhci
irq 121:          0  1-edge dmar1        irq 166:          0  3145732-edge xhci
irq 122:          0  458752-edge aerdr   irq 167:          0  3145733-edge xhci
irq 123:          0  466944-edge aerdr   irq 168:          0  3145734-edge xhci
irq 124:          0  475136-edge aerdr   irq 169:          0  3145735-edge xhci
irq 127:          2  1064960-edge pcie   irq 170:          0  3670016-edge enp7
irq 129:          0  1114112-edge pcie   irq 171:       3966  3670017-edge enp7
irq 130:     426322  327680-edge xhci_   irq 172:       3966  3670018-edge enp7
irq 131:          0  28835840-edge xhc   irq 173:       3966  3670019-edge enp7
irq 132:      36531  1572864-edge thun   irq 174:       3966  3670020-edge enp7
irq 133:      36526  1572865-edge thun   irq 175:         37  360448-edge mei_m
irq 148:       5525  56623104-edge nvm   irq 176:       1077  514048-edge snd_h
irq 149:      44388  32768-edge i915     irq 177:          0                   
irq 150:       6653  56623105-edge nvm   irq 179:          0                   
irq 151:       6465  56623106-edge nvm                                         

loop0              61r               0   nvme0n1p5              66r            
loop1            1779r               0   nvme0n1p6              40r            
loop2              53r               0   nvme0n1p7           30356r           1
loop3              39r               0   loop8              50r               0
loop4              39r               0   loop9              40r               0
loop5              38r               0   loop10              36r               
loop6            2663r               0   loop11              40r               
loop7              35r               0   loop12              37r               
nvme0n1           31701r           142   loop13              37r               
nvme0n1p1            1061r               loop14            9867r               
nvme0n1p2              32r               loop15               5r               
nvme0n1p3              42r               sda             2945r             373w
nvme0n1p4              42r                                                     

enp7s0      TX 0.00B         RX 0.00B         wlp107s0    TX 910.95KiB     RX 35.24MiB     
lo          TX 55.30KiB      RX 55.30KiB
```

Here is the output of lsusb -v (it was too big to include in the post): [lsusb -v](https://pastebin.com/WfRxaHXN)

Answer (score 1):

probably I am a bit late here. I had the same problem with the same hardware. The solution that worked for me is:
under Settings > Privacy > Thunderbolt you will find your device. You need to authorize it in order to have the usb-a ports working.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem and installing Display Link drivers solved it for me.

[Download page](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads)

[Instructions page](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-legacy-ubun)

Or ;TLDR:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install libdrm-dev

# download the install script from the provided link
# make it executable
chmod +x ./displaylink-driver-xxxxx.run
sudo ./displaylink-driver-xxxxx.run
```

* change xxx for your version of a file

I have also disabled secure boot not sure if there was a real need.